# Фоновая картинка во фрейме

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы во фрейме фоновая картинка открывалась во весь размер и отходила от краев (краев фрейма) на 1-2px?

Answer (score 1):

```
background:url('./картинка.png');
background-size:100%;
background-origin:padding-box;
padding:2px;
```

Что-то типо того?